# AngularJS Stalled Requests to REST API

Tags: angularjs, rest

I have an AngularJS (1.4) app that relies upon $http.get requests to a REST API.

There are two types of request, one for "Search Results", and one for "View Profile". Sometimes (but not consistently so), the request for "View Profile" is not returned. Checking in the Chrome network tab it's marked as Stalled.

Looking this up it seems maybe I am hitting the Chrome max connections limit - but I don't understand how this can be the case as surely the "connection" is not created again each time an $http.get request is called?

Does anybody have any ideas?

Simplified code below:

```
app.factory('garageService', function($http,$q) {

    var garageService = {};
    var url = ''; // CAN'T SHARE
    var token = ''; // CAN'T SHARE
    var radius = 50;

    // GET SEARCH RESULTS
    garageService.getList = function(lat,lng) {

      var deferred = $q.defer();

      if(window.XDomainRequest){
        //XDR Version for IE
      } else {
        $http.get(url+'/'+token+'/list/'+lat+'/'+lng+'/'+radius, { cache: true, timeout: 10000 }).success(function(response){
          deferred.resolve(response);
        }).error(function(){
          deferred.reject();
        });
      }

      return deferred.promise;

    }
    // GET VIEW PROFILE 
    garageService.getProfile = function(id) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      if(window.XDomainRequest){
        //XDR Version for IE
      } else {
        $http.get(url+'/'+token+'/get/'+id, { cache: true, timeout: 10000 }).success(function(response){
          deferred.resolve(response);
        }).error(function(){
          deferred.reject();
        });
      }
      return deferred.promise;

    }
    return garageService;

});
```

And here are the response headers from a working request:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: //CAN'T SHARE
Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Thu, 31 Dec 2015 10:28:37 GMT
ETag:"1451557717"
Expires:Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=2, max=200
Last-Modified:Thu, 31 Dec 2015 10:28:37 GMT
Server:Apache
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.3
```

Comment: sounds more like a php back end problem. Also don't see why you need different request method for IE

Comment: Thanks - different request methods are for IE8 Cross-Origin Requests. I'll try getting the API set up on another server and see if that impacts it.

Comment: Just to note though, that the Chrome docs suggest that "Stalled" is not a server issue, rather it's a browser issue. Will try anyway though.

Comment: any Solution for this ?